# Best practice for Python: assert command() == False

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

I wonder what is better/best:

```
>>> def command():
...     return False
...
>>> assert command() == False
>>> assert command() is False
>>> assert not command()
```

Cheers, Markus

Comment: Is `command` a function?It returns bool value?

Comment: @iMom0 in an unittest context, you often have a `command()` under test, which have to return `False`.

Comment: @mhubig: if you're using PyUnit, the `assertFalse()` method is probably better style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most pythonic is the third. It is equivalent to:

```
assert bool(command()) != False
```

Answer (score 10):

Coding conventions can be studied here: 
[PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

There you will find:

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==

```
Yes:   if greeting:
No:    if greeting == True:
Worse: if greeting is True:
```

Comment: Why is ``is True`` considered to be worse than ``== True``?

Comment: So this probably means `assert not command()` is most pythonic, as @themiurgo states!

Comment: Sometimes I have variables that are True, False or None. if not greeting: doesn't distinguish between False and None. So would I not want to use if greeting is None and if greeting is False? Why would this be a mistake?

Comment: Testing whether a variable that defaults to None was set to some other value, should indeed use `if greeting is not None`. [PEP 8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)
Still, [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is another concept: _greeting is false_ when its Python class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object. So `greeting is False`, just ignores the `greeting = ''` case, which does not make it a mistake, but less pythonic